# Finding braches of equilibria

Tags: differential-geometry, dynamical-systems

> Consider the system of two equations in three variables $(x,y,z)$:
>   $$\left\{ \begin{array}{rl}
> x+y+z+x^7+y^7+z^9 &= 0\\
> x-y+z+1-\cos z &=0
> \end{array}\right.$$
>
> The point $x^* = (0,0,0)^T$ is obviously a solution to this system. Compute the number of solution branches through this point and the tangent directions along all solution branches.

I don't really have an idea of how to solve this question. I tried plotting this, but I don't seem to have any branch points?

On the other hand I could calculate the Jacobian:
$$DF(x) = \begin{pmatrix}1+7x^6 & 1+7y^6 & 1+9z^8\\1 & -1 & 1+\sin z \end{pmatrix}$$
Which evaluates to 
$$DF(x^*) = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 1\\1 & -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
Should I look for a right zero vector?
Somehting like $(1,0,-1)^T$

Comment: If I understand and remember correctly, the system of $m$ equations in $R^n$ which has rank equal to $m$ describes $(n-m)$-dimensional submanifold. And if I apply this statement correctly in your case the solution set is a 1-dimensional submanifold which means that you have only one branch of solutions.